# Several curl requests, but one authorization, to IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis, curl, asp.net-web-api

Situation:

We have IIS Server in company and MVC web site, which also has a lot web api controllers. Methods in those controllers require authorization by Active Directory account. Also we have several Linux machines.

In my examples I use curl for Windows.

We need to write script, which do a lot of requests to server (grab information from web site and post files to it, whichever what we got).

When I try authorize everything works good. Server asks by password and i get correct answer:

```
PS C:\Users\Dent> curl.exe --url http://localhost:32060/website/api/controller/get --ntlm --user Domain\Dent
```

Question:
Is there a way to authorize only once? It is a critical moment. I tried a lot of variations:

```
PS C:\Users\Dent> curl.exe --url http://localhost:32060/website/api/controller/get --ntlm --user Domain\Dent  --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar newcookies.txt

PS C:\Users\Dent> curl.exe --url http://localhost:32060/website/api/controller/get --ntlm  --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar newcookies.txt
```

or

```
PS C:\Users\Dent> curl.exe --url http://localhost:32060/website/api/controller/get --ntlm --user Domain\Dent  --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar newcookies.txt

PS C:\Users\Dent> curl.exe --url http://localhost:32060/website/api/controller/get --ntlm --user Domain\Dent -H 'Authorization: NTLM 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'
```

And no progress.

In powershell it looks simple:

```
$session = ''
Invoke-WebRequest -SessionVariable session -Uri http://localhost:32060/website/api/controller/get -Credential Domain\Dent

#In second request we use the same session variable and no credentials needed. 

Invoke-WebRequest -WebSession $session -Uri http://localhost:32060/website/api/controller/get/2
```

I need to present some working example for our Linux-team. Two days of googling and no progress. There is a night, but i'm still in office=) 
Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question implied here is "*How to keep track of an NTLM HTTP session in `bash`?*" in a way similar to how it is done with PowerShell session variable.

However the real question is

> Question: I need to present some working example for our Linux-team.

This question is both easier to answer and not specific enough to allow for multiple solution.

You could use `python` or `php` instead of pure shell with `curl`.

In Python using the `requests` ([Requests: HTTP for Humans](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)) and `requests_ntlm` libraries you could proceed interactively as follows:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from getpass import getpass
>>> from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
>>> username='Domain\\Dent'
>>> password=getpass()
Password:
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> s.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username,password)
>>> r1 = s.get('http://localhost:32060/website/api/controller/get')
>>> r1.status_code
200
>>> r2 = s.get('http://localhost:32060/website/api/controller/get/2')
>>> r2.status_code
200
```

You authenticate session once and later can issue many requests without typing the password again.

> Question: Is there a way to authorize only once (using `curl` command)?

No, it is not possible. Windows Challenge/Response authentication is based on the connection security model. NTLM negotiaties authentication of requests within one TCP connection. Cookies do not hold all the necessary security tokens. It is not possible to share a TCP connection between two unrelated processes, therefore each process spawned with the `curl` command would require new authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the answer=) We came to very similar solution. For most of linux-users we write python client. Others of them find how to use Kerberos authentication in linux-curl. They use mvc-api directly. So everybody is happy.

Comment: @re-gor Answering your own questions is generally encouraged here. Whenever you have solved your problem yourself and did not get suitable answers from the community, please do share your experience.

Comment: @Chubarov, yes, I know. But for me this solution looked like bad workarround. And I was highly interested in better way to resolve the issue. 
Moreover your answer made clear the moment with "only one authorization". I could not do it. So, thank you again =)